# Android cast not discover smart tv

Tags: android, google-cast

I am newbie in android cast. I have android app using default cast ID. It discovering my chromecast device but I have a problem with found my Samsung Smart TV. I want to use cast to stream audio from url. 
What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cast SDK is to cast to Cast Devices such as Chromecast, "Samsung Smart TVs" are not Cast devices.